# Why does the FAA require special authorization to act as PIC in the North American T-28 Trojan?

Tags: pilot-certification, type-ratings, faa-approval

[This airplane](http://www.flugzeuginfo.net/acdata_php/acdata_t28_en.php) doesn't have a max gross takeoff weight of more than 12,500 pounds nor does it have a turbine engine.

[image]

The FAA requires special authorization to act as PIC in order to fly it.  What is the reason?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As the T-28 is a vintage military surplus aircraft it is normally certificated in the Experimental-Exhibition category. For most aircraft in this category, there is no type rating in the traditional sense. For years, the FAA managed these aircraft and pilot qualifications for them on a case-by-case basis. Approval to fly them was (and for some vintage aircraft still is) granted by a Letter of Authorization (LOA).

About 15-20 years ago, in an effort to reduce the regulatory burden on both the FAA and pilots they moved to a process that more closely aligns with type ratings. It is managed under the [**Vintage & Experimental Aircraft Program**](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/vintage_experimental/).

The stated coverage of the program is:

> This program standardizes pilot certification in the following U.S.
> aircraft:
>
> - Vintage Type Certificated aircraft which require a type rating
> - Experimental turbine-powered aircraft
> - Experimental aircraft with a maximum gross weight in excess of 12,500 pounds, or
> - Experimental piston powered aircraft with an engine over 800 HP and a Vne (never exceed speed) greater than 250 knots

The T-28 falls under the last bullet as it has more than 800 hp.